# HTTP headers not getting sent with fetch()

Tags: javascript, rest, http-headers

I'm trying to configure the backend API on my app and here's the code to send a request:

```
static async xhr(endpoint, args, method) {
  const url = `${API_SERVER}${endpoint}`;
  let formBody = [];
  for (let property in args) {
      let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
      let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(args[property]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");
  let options = Object.assign({ method: method }, args ? { body: formBody } : null );
  try {
    let headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };
    accessToken = 'bdi8HD8js91jdoach7234h';
    if(accessToken != null)
        headers['Authorization'] = accessToken;
    options.headers = headers;
    return fetch(url, options).then( resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        let json = resp.json();
        if(resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
            if (resp.ok) {
                return json
            }
        } else {
            return {};
        }
        return json.then(err => {throw err});
    });
  } catch (error) {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Note: I debugged and found that the headers are correctly getting added to the options variable, but for some reason, the server isn't receiving the `Authorization` header.

I used `Postman` to send the exact same request with the exact same headers and I'm getting the correct response via it. I have no idea what's wrong, except it would only be so if the headers aren't getting sent in the first place.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: try `headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': accessToken
  })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `headers` option has to be an instance of [`Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers). You can transform your current `headers` object to a `Headers` instance by passing it to its constructor like this:

```
const headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
});
```

*Note that I also replaced `let` with `const` since that variable is not going to be reassigned.*

To change a header or add a new header to that `Headers` instance, you can use the [`set` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/set). Instead of `headers['Authorization'] = accessToken` you'd do ...

```
headers.set('Authorization', accessToken)
```

Comment: Okay I tried to do this and it wasn't working still, but then I found out that for some reason it was automatically converting 'Authorization' to 'authorization' and at the API side, it was not able to read the lower-cased authorization as 'Authorization', due to which the error happened. I have fixed it, but any reason why it's converting 'Authorization' to 'authorization'?

Comment: @KetanMalhotra That's because HTTP headers are – according to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) – case-insensitive. Some web frameworks have a method that helps you deal with this. Express for example has [`Request.get`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get) which returns the value of a header matching it case-insensitive*ly*.